# Brezis-Kato theorem

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, elliptic-pde, regularity

Let $n\geq 3$, and $u$ satisfies
$$
-\Delta u=K(x)u^{\frac{n+2}{n-2}}
\quad x\in B_1\setminus \{0\},
$$ where

- $|K(x)|\leq A$ in $B_1\setminus \{0\}$, and
- $u\geq 0$ in $B_1\setminus \{0\}$.

Can we use the Brezis-Kato theorem to show $u\in L^{\infty}(B_{0.9})$?

Comment: usually in the Brezis-Kato theorem you need a linear bound for the RHS $-\Delta u=g(x,u(x))$ i.e. $$|g(x,u(x))|\leq \alpha(x)(1+|u(x)|).$$ But in this article they also cover a generalization with power exponent https://arxiv.org/pdf/2202.11408.pdf "Brezis–Kato Type Regularity Results for Higher Order Elliptic Operators."

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I still have a question that if 0 is removable singularity so it's bounded near 0 and have $L^{\infty}$ bound near 0. sorry for late comment.